# Service running in the background

Tags: android, service, background-process, android-binder

What I want to achieve is to create a Service(?) which starts/gets registered once Application gets installed and keeps monitor items stored in Array. These items are products with expiry dates so if today is the day of expiry I want to show a notification about it no matter if application is currently running or not.

I have already searched internet and Android developers website for an answer and here is what I learned:

1. I need to create a Service which in onStartCommand return "START_STICKY" and specify in my android Manifest.xml file that Activity is in SingleTop start mode.
2. I need to bind this Service with my Activity to pass data in one way or another.

What I don't know how to do is:

1. Where to start the Service so there is only 1 instance of it?
2. How to check expiry dates stored in an Array (in Service or Activity) for example once a day?
3. Array with products, should it be static so it can be accessed either from Activity and Service or I should create separate instance of it and pass data accordingly via Binder?

Generally, I know the basics and how it should work but I lack a concept how to implement it so it will be effective.

Thanks for all answers! :)

// EDIT

Some code of my custom Service as for now:

```
class ExpiryMonitorService : Service() {

private val productsArray: ArrayList<ProductEntry> = ArrayList()

// Binder which will be given to clients
private val mBinder: IBinder = LocalBinder()

inner class LocalBinder : Binder() {

    fun getService() : ExpiryMonitorService {

        // Return this instance of ExpiryMonitorService so clients can call public methods
        return this@ExpiryMonitorService

    }
}

override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder {

    return mBinder
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    return START_STICKY // Restart this service if it gets killed by the system
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer isn't a service.  Its an AlarmManager (or JobScheduler) set to the expiration of the closes to expiration item, and a database of items and expiration dates.  When the job goes off, it sends the notification and schedules the next alarm/job based on the data in the db.

Service isn't the answer because a service can be killed at any time for resources.  In addition, on modern versions of Android a Service has limits to how much background processing it can do before being killed.  Neither of these makes for a good monitoring solution.  Luckily you don't actually need monitoring, you just need to be alerted at a certain time, which is perfect for an alarm.

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer I was looking for. :) I will try to implement it either with AlarmManager or JobSheduler, depending on my needs (i need to check what are those first :D) and post any questions if needed.

Comment: @BartoszKubacki The two fill the same role, but JobScheduler is newer and easier to work with.  Its just older phones won't have it.  They allow you to schedule your app to be woken up and launch a specific BroadcastReceiver at a given time (with a lot of additional options on JobScheduler that makes it easier to use).

Comment: I believe I have successfully implemented solution with JobSheduler but I can't find any good way of scheduling an event at specific time once a day, let's say at 8 AM. Am I wrong or it should be done with Alarm Manager?

Comment: @BartoszKubacki JobScheduler is sufficient for that.  There should be a periodic option.  Or worst case one job can schedule the next.

Comment: maybe you are right but how to implement it? Periodic job will be done at a specific interval but, for example if I will schedule a task with 24h interval, I don't have control over at what time exactly it will be executed - especially if device is rebooted in the meantime. AlarmManager seems to be a real answer here as it gives functionality to specify exact time when task should be executed.